# Pulling users friends profile pictures from social networking sites like facebook,twitter,google plus

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, twitter, google-plus

I want to confirm whether pulling users's profile pics from all major social networking sites like facebook,twitter,google plus is possible or not.

For facebook, I got the solutions:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=[oauth_token]&fields=name,id,picture
```

Which api we can use in twitter,google plus for the same? Is it allowed?

**Edited:**

For twitter, we can get friends profile pic using

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google+, you probably want

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible
```

(Providing your auth token, and possibly limiting it to particular fields if you want.) Keep in mind there are some limitations of what you'll actually get back - only public information is available, so if the user has limited the visibility of the circles they share, you won't necessarily see everyone.

See https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list for full details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if the site provides an API for doing so It seems you've found twitters and facebooks. In most countries it however is illegal to "scrape" sites for information such as user profile photos using spiders/crawlers.

Comment: Since api is exposed, I don't think so it is illegal to pull profile pics and these sites provide information based on user premissions

Comment: Its not if you're using their API, but if you used other methods it may be.

Comment: Yes.I understand that :)